# Why this simple JavaScript code not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a code within a form input such as when the user clicks on the form element (onfocus), the value of the element disappears, but if a user click on any other input element after that (without filling up the previous input element of the form) than the value of the previous element reappears.

The  **HTML** code is shown below:

```
<label id="color_text">Forename:</label><br />
<input id="f1" class="form-control" type="text" name="forename"    value="Forename" /><br /><br />
```

The JavaScript i am trying to run is shown below:

```
<script>
    var new_id = document.getElementById("f1");

    new_id.onfocus = function(){
        if (new_id.value == "Forename"){
        new_id.value = "";
        }
     };

    new_id.onblur = function() {
        if (new_id.value == ""){
        new_id.value = "Forename"; 
        }
    };
```

Comment: Works ok for me... https://jsfiddle.net/mfdjknw7/

Comment: Any errors in the console? I bet there is one about `null or undefined`. And do you realize most modern browsers support placeholder? No JavaScript is needed.

Comment: where exactly are you running the script? is it after the elements are defined or before?

Comment: The console error its showing is new_id is null

Comment: I am running the script at the end, I have tried writing it on a different file and included the js. file at the end, after all the elements are defined.

Comment: What browser Are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest browser both Chrome and Firefox, never have and never will use IE

Answer (score 0):

For maximum compatibility you should use `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` (whatever is available). So for focus event something like this:

```
function addEvent(element, evnt, funct){
  if (element.attachEvent)
   return element.attachEvent('on'+evnt, funct);
  else
   return element.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
}

addEvent(new_id, 'focus', function() {
  if (new_id.value == "Forename"){
      new_id.value = "";
  }
});
```

You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick/6348597#6348597) about events binding. And probably use placeholder in first place, if I am right about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Should make zero difference

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/bigneo/7j217d8y/

I think the problem is your methods are not seen by the document. You could wrap them inside `document.ready`

Something like this, but requires jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your methods here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine in Chrome 44. What's your browser?

And why don't you use `placeholder` attribute in the `<input>` label?

Comment: I am using the latest version of Chrome and I know placeholder is an option for me, but that doesn't answer the fact why shouldn't this code work.

Comment: I'm sure your code works in Chrome. Did you post all code? Because the code in your post missed the `</script>` end label

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, you just need to tell the browser when to run it. Wrap it in this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    // code goes here

});
```

This is a much better option for vanilla JS rather than importing the whole JQuery library just to use `$(document).ready(function()`